# How to count the rows in a table using EF5 if the count exceeds an int?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

How can EF5 be used to get the rowcount of a table if the number of rows exceeds the size of an int?  All of the overloads for Count() seem to return an int.

Comment: What about `LongCount()`?

Comment: Like @KingKing says, `LongCount()` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337729.aspx

Comment: You've GOT to be kidding me!  It was there all along.  UGH!

Comment: If 'KingKong' could post it as an answer, the OP could mark it as 'the answer'.